# automatically set current iteration in azure devops on column change

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem, work-item-type

our team works in scrum and we recently implemented azure devops as out planning tool. As we like the view of the kanban board we'd like to integrate this with our iterations and keep both in sync.

Most of it can be achived using states, ok, obvious. But I'm wondering if I could set a rule for the work items that, if a certain status is set the @currentIteration prop is set to the iteration path field. Is this possible somehow? It seems I cannot select the iteration path field as an action target in work item rules.

Comment: Please use REST API as the answer suggests to have a try. If this is helpful to you, please sign it as a right one to benefit others.

Comment: Hey, yes. Thanks for the hint. Wasn‘t around to long! I accepted the answer as it‘s the best solution so far! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can not update the iteration path through work item rules. That`s maybe your custom app through rest API. You can:

1. Find the current iteration: [Iterations - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)
2. Create wiql (like, find work items with Active state and iteration <> current): [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)
3. Update work items: [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)